# Discord.py message scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, discord, discord.py, bots

i am trying to do a message scrpper bot with discord.py and i have a problem. With the followign I am able to detect all the new messages that are recived on my account (groups and dm) but when i try to get the content of that messages it returs an empty str. It only returns the message content when I am tagged or when I am the author. Anyone knows what can I do?
The code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot= commands.Bot(command_prefix='')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message)
    print(message.clean_content)
    print(message.system_content)   
    print(message.content)


bot.run(token,bot=False)
```

As you can see, I have tried to use the clean_content, the system_content and the content methods in order to get the message content.

Thx

Comment: I assume you are using a selfbot? (`bot.run(token,bot=False)`) These are no longer supported and violate the ToS. I doubt you will get any help on that question here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as stated by Dominik, don't use a script on your client. This isn't just against TOS but also highly annoying to other users if used with malicious intent

Second, to store a message in a text file:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("filename.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{message.author.name}: {message.content}\n")
```